# Translation file support

Tags: android, string, translation

This is not a **coding** problem, but more of a theoretical question. I know SO sticks to coding, but then I couldn't find any relevant answer to my question.

I'm developing an application (Android) regarding *providing support for new languages and quickly adding translations for new features in existing languages*. I wanted to know about some resources to study on it, learn about the various common options that needs to be implemented in the application.

Basically, my doubt is what are the different options in the application that **must be** implemented for *providing support for new languages and quickly adding translations for new features in existing languages*.

Please post any useful links to posts/blogs/scholastic articles/books/ or anything relevant.

Suppose a user has to convert a string from language `X` to language `Y` that may not be included in standard language packs. For this, translatable strings are used. Two mandatory options (in the App) will be:

1. A User Selects the string to be translated from language `X`.
2. Choose the language `Y` (from a pop-up) to which it has to be translated.

Like this, how many different options should I implement for a decent App.

Comment: I would recommend editing your question to explain precisely what you mean by "Support for using a standard data format for translatable (English) and translated strings".

Comment: It is still not clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @MaciejGórski: Please see my edited question. I've tried explaining it through an example this time. I hope, it helps.

Comment: Are you asking how to localize your application?

Comment: @TJThind: Sort of Yes. I want to convert data gathered from external sources (textual) into other languages.

Comment: @ptokya Try taking a look here, http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html